# How to disable select functionality in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uitextview, subclassing

I want to create a text display area (either UILabel or UITextView) in my iPhone app which (1) allows scrolling and (2) does not allow selection. I have tried the following techniques unsuccessfully:

1. Basic UILabel: Didn't allow
   scrolling, and clipped text to the
   bottom of UILabel space on screen.
2. Giant UILabel within a UIScrollView: the UILabel kept placing the text (vertically) at the center of the giant UILabel, so it often was outside of my UIScrollView.
3. UITextView: So far this approach has worked the best, because it scrolls and does not clip the text. I can even subclass UITextView to enable [resizing the text to fit within the textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038975/resize-font-size-to-fill-uitextview), and [passing any touch events to the superview to detect taps & swipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042930/successful-swipe-in-uitextview/3385167#3385167). **But, when the user taps and holds on the text itself, the text selection interface appears.** I am not interested in this interface and it actually is distracting from the user's experience. I have tried to subclass `canPerformAction:withSender:`, but apparently this function is called *after* the tap event--not before it.

**Does anyone know how to disable the text selection interface in UITextView, without also disabling scrolling?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take option number 2, but set the `numberOfLines` property on your `UILabel` to `0`. This will set the number of lines to 'unlimited' and prevent the vertical centring of the text.

Don't forget to set the `lineBreakMode` property to `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` so that your text doesn't run off the side of the `UILabel`.

Comment: This worked for me -- but UIScrollView is tricky. I still needed to dynamically change the size of each UILabel so that the text appeared at the top.