# How to prevent user from selecting text on textView? / ios / xcode

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a few scrollable textViews and I would like to remove the select feature from them. When scrolling, once in a while the user can be a bit upset when the text is being selected and not scrolled.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397857/how-to-disable-select-functionality-in-uitextview