# How to enable swipe gesture for a UITextView

Tags: iphone, ipad, gesture-recognition

How do I enable the swipe gesture recognition for a UITextView?

This is my code and the event attach to it is not firing. It works for taps just not for swipes.

```
// Add swipe support for easy textview content clean up
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(eraseTextWithSwipe:)];
[targetContent addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
[swipe release];
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if any of the suggestions in this question will help; there were no accepted answers in it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042930/successful-swipe-in-uitextview

Comment: Thank you for your comment but that doesn't apply, I have seen it. That uses a technique that is not recommended by Apple in iPhone 4.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works well for me.

You need to set the delegate (referring to the code above)

```
swipe.delegate = self;
```

then you need to add a delegate to track multiple gestures, which will be able to track the swipe and the scrolling

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGesture
{
    yourTextbox.scrollEnabled = NO;
    return YES;
}
```

re-enable the scroll in the callback function (in the example above eraseTextWithSwipe)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you. Your solution works. I just had to set the delegate and return YES in the mentioned delegate method.
If not for usability reasons, you don't have to disable the scrolling on the UITextView.